# Is there a way to find the name of the Permission using the PermissionsBitField.Flags? (discordjs v.14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to check if the bot has certain permissions in a server. So, I would like to make it return something like: "I am lacking the permission: MANAGE_GUILD". However, I only have the PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageGuild. So, is there a way to return the name of the permission using the PermissionsBitField.Flags?

Thank you in advance! (Also, yes it is supposed to be for discordjs v.14)

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the name of the field which permissions this PermissionBitField holds using `Object.keys(PermissionBitField.Flags)`. The code snippet below uses this to create an array of the human readable names from the PermissionBitField object:

```
import {PermissionsBitField} from 'discord.js';

function permissionsNames(permissions: PermissionsBitField) : string[] {
  const result = [];

  for (const perm of Object.keys(PermissionsBitField.Flags)) {
    if (permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags[perm])) {
      result.push(perm);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(permissionsNames( new PermissionsBitField(268550160n)));
```

This will result in

```json
 [
   'ManageChannels',
   'EmbedLinks',
   'AttachFiles',
   'ReadMessageHistory',
   'ManageRoles'
 ]
```

You can also use this to get the name of exactly one field:

```
import {PermissionsBitField} from 'discord.js';

function getPermissionName(permission: bigint) : string {
  for (const perm of Object.keys(PermissionsBitField.Flags)) {
    if (PermissionsBitField.Flags[perm] === permission) {
      return perm;
    }
  }
  return 'UnknownPermission';
}

console.log(getPermissionName(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageGuild));
```

This will then result in `ManageGuild`, which is what you are looking for!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that! Tysm!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```js
const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');

if (!message.guild.me.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageGuild)) return message.reply({content: "I am lacking the permission: MANAGE_GUILD"})
```

Comment: Haii, ty for your response. But does that mean I have to check for every permission whether the bot has it?

Comment: that's because you forget value here `{name: "Version du bot :", botversion},`